# Using IPrinciple.Identity.Name as a key in a dataBase to identify user's rows

Tags: asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication

I'm writing a small intranet app that uses Windows Authentication and Asp.Net MVC.
I need to store various bits of data in a db against each user.
As far as I can tell the IPrinciple object does not seem to have something like a unique id. So I was thinking I could just use User.Identity.Name as a unique value to identify rows in my db.
Is this a bad idea? Is there an alternative to this approach?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a User table that included an identity column as the id. When a person accesses the site, I would check the user table for that individuals unique id, and read it if it exists, or insert a new row if the user is new.

Login names can be long, and that could affect your indexes depending on the expected size of your data.

Comment: Yes that what I was thinking - what I'm really asking though is what part of the IPrinciple.Identity object should I store in the db - i.e. what should I use to look up a user in the user table you descibed?
Thanks for taking the time answer - much appreciated.